# Proof the limit of sequence $\{cos(a_n)\}_{n=0}^{\infty} $ where $a_n \in \mathbb R$ and $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$ is equal to $1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I want to proof the limit of the sequence $\{cos(a_n)\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ where $a_n \in \mathbb R$ and $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$ is equal to 1.

By intuition $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} cos(a_n) = cos(lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n)$, however I'm not familiar with any theorem allowing me to move the limit into a function.

I must prove: $|cos(a_n) - 1| \le \epsilon$. Since $cos$ is monotonic decreasing on the interval $[0;\pi/2]$ my idea is:

Given $\epsilon > 0$. Suppose $\epsilon + 1 \in [0;1]$. Then choose $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $a_n \le cos^{-1}(\epsilon + 1)$ for all $n \ge N$. Otherwise if $\epsilon + 1 \notin [0;1]$ then choose $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $a_n \le cos^{-1}(1/2)$.

Advice is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rigorous approach

1. Using your definition of the sine function, prove that $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin x=0$. You may want to remark that $0 \leq |\sin x| \leq |x|$ when $x$ is "small".
2. Prove that $\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{1-x^2}=1$.
3. Use 1., 2. and the identity $\cos^2 x = 1-\sin^2 x$ to prove that $\lim_{x \to 0} \cos x =1$.

Comment: Thanks, both of your answers are brilliant. But your answer reflect what is presented in the book.

Answer (score 3):

The equality $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(a_n)=\cos(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n)$$ is simply the continuity of the cosine at $0$.

**Edit:** here is a proof. The cosine is continuous at $0$. So, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$
|1-\cos t|<\epsilon,\ \ \ \mbox{ whenever }|t|<\delta.
$$
Now choose $m$ such that $|a_n|<\delta$ for all $n>m$. Then, for all such $n$,
$$
|1-\cos a_n|<\epsilon.
$$

Comment: But since my textbook doesn't mention anything about this equality - I guess it comes from real analysis ? I must do a proof without it I guess.

Comment: That said, does my proof makes sense (valid?)

Comment: You won't be able to prove it without using the continuity of the cosine: the equality fails for discontinuous functions. Regarding your argument: first $1+\epsilon$ is not in the range of the cosine, so $\cos^{-1}$ does not apply; also, the cosine is decreasing, so when you apply it to an inequality it reverses it.

Comment: You said that $\epsilon>0$. Then $1+\epsilon>1$.